# My Minecraft skin just won't work

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Whenever I try to load a skin it doesn't work and it's just a green blob. I've tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it a custom skin? Can you share the skin in question?